# Spring Boot custom SSL key-store loading logic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I'm using Spring boot 2.x and I need to configure the SSL on it.

To enable the SSL it's easy: just filling these properties:

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/mycertificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=mypassword
security.require-ssl=true
```

But I need this additional behaviour: Instead of loading the certificate from a specific path (server.ssl.key-store) I need to have a custom loading  logic: I need to implement this custom way using, for example, the AWS Secrets service or similar.

So, is it possible? Is there a possibility to extend this default behaviour in Spring specifying a custom loader or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

spring boot uses by default tomcat and tomcat can only be configured with the properties which you mentioned in your question. So it is not flexible and I think it is not possible to accomplish this with the default spring boot configuration with tomcat. I faced similar challenges and the solution I applied was to replace the embedded tomcat server with jetty. With Jetty it is possible to configure the ssl properties on runtime while getting it from for example your aws secrets service. See this project as an example: https://github.com/Hakky54/java-tutorials/tree/main/instant-server-ssl-reloading/server

So what I can recommend is to first exclude tomcat from your dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Include Jetty server to spring boot:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Bean
public SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory() {
    return fooService.createSslContextFactory();
}
```

```java
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory(SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory) {
    JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();

    JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer = server -> {
        ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server, sslContextFactory);
        serverConnector.setPort(8443);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{serverConnector});
    };
    factory.setServerCustomizers(Collections.singletonList(jettyServerCustomizer));

    return factory;
}
```